# Combining two classes that have partial classes inside

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, partial-classes

Not really sure how to phrase the title sorry.

I have two classes I generated from a JSON to c# online converter. These classes are so I can deserialise some JSON objects and turn them into objects I can use elsewhere in my program. The converter I used gave me these two classes:

```
namespace testing
{

    public partial class stopEvent
    {
        [JsonProperty("event")]
        public Event1 Event { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Event1
    {
        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ID")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sessID")]
        public long SessId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("startTime")]
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("endTime")]
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Percentage")]
        public string Percentage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my second object which represents a starting event.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace testing
{
    public partial class startEvent
    {
        [JsonProperty("event")]
        public Event Event { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Event
    {
        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ID")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sessID")]
        public long SessId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("startTime")]
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Number")]
        public long Number { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("rfID")]
        public string RfId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("startPercentage")]
        public string startPercentage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I use these in my code and deserialise the json and convert it into objects, it works fine. I had to rename the Event from the second class to Event1 as otherwise it would have the same name as the first partial class.

However, I noticed there were quite a few repeated fields in both classes, so I thought I could make a super class and then both can inherit from there. This was my super class:

```
public class Event
{
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("sessID")]
    public long SessId { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("startTime")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("Number")]
    public long Number { get; set; }
}
```

I then changed the classes so they looked like this:

```
public class stopEvent : Event
{
    [JsonProperty("Percentage")]
    public string Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

With the same for the startEvent. However, when I try to implement this in the deserialise part of the program it doesn't work - all the values come back as null and I'm not sure why.

EDIT:

Deserialising is as follows:

```
        stopEvent StopEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<stopEvent>(message);
```

Comment: "*when I try to implement this in the deserialise part of the program it doesn't work*" -- please include this code in your question

Comment: @canton7 added in to the bottom

Comment: Don't inherit  StopEvent:Event that is not correct.  Use Event as a property of StopEvent public Event Event{get;set;}.

Answer (score 2):

Before your change, your `startEvent` class had a single property called `event`, which then contained further data. The corresponding JSON would look something like:

```json
{
    "startEvent":
    {
        "Name": "...",
        "ID": "...",
        ...
    }
}
```

After your change, your `startEvent` class now inherits from `Event`, rather than having `Event` as a property. This means that the corresponding JSON would look something like:

```json
{
    "Name": "...",
    "ID": "...",
    ...
}
```

See how you've lost the "startEvent" member?

You need to keep the structure of the objects the same, but you can still introduce a base class which is shared by `Event` and `Event1`.

You probably meant to do something like this. I've taken the liberty of renaming your types to be a bit clearer:

```
// Common properties between all event data types
public abstract class EventDataBase
{
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sessID")]
    public long SessId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("startTime")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Number")]
    public long Number { get; set; }
}

// Fields which just the start event data has
public class StartEventData : EventDataBase
{
    [JsonProperty("rfID")]
    public string RfId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("startPercentage")]
    public string startPercentage { get; set; }
}

// Start event, which uses the start event data
public class StartEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("event")]
    public StartEventData Event { get; set; }
}

// Fields which just the stop event data has
public class StopEventData : EventDataBase
{
    [JsonProperty("Number")]
    public long Number { get; set; }
}

// Stopevent, which uses the start event data
public class StopEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("event")]
    public StopEventData Event { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You changed the structure of the object, so the JSON does not match up anymore.  `stopEvent` used to have an property `Event`, but you changed it to inherit from `Event`, so it no longer has that property - instead it has all the properties directly on itself, which is going to not sync with the JSON anymore.

You can see this if you create an instance of `stopEvent` yourself and serialize it, then compare to the JSON you are trying to deserialize from.  They'll have a different structure.

The fix is either to revert your changes, or to update the incoming JSON to match your new object, if you have control over that.

Comment: How would I change the stopEvent so that it does sync with the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

In order for considering the inherited properties. You can try adding the "MemberSerialisation" attribute to the sub class

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.Fields)]
```

Comment: `MemberSerialization` controls whether fields or properties are serialized. It has nothing to do with inheritance at all?